# Get Servlet session attributes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, session, servlets

I have a raffle button that's being enabled or disabled based on Session Attributes I've set using Servlets.

It should be disabled if either of this is true

1. the `enBancCount` is equals to zero
2. It's not a valid day

Here is my code:

```
<button id="raffleBtn" type="submit"
     ${sessionScope.enBancCount == 0 || !sessionScope.validDay ? 'disabled' : ''}>
     Raffle
</button>
```

I'm currently using JSP EL to add the `disabled` attribute on the button based on the two conditions above. But now, before enabling it, I also have to check if majority attended on this raffle.

I added the following input fields for checking the attendance:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="attendance" value=""> ATTENDEE 1
<input type="checkbox" name="attendance" value=""> ATTENDEE 2
<input type="checkbox" name="attendance" value=""> ATTENDEE ...
<input type="checkbox" name="attendance" value=""> ATTENDEE 6
```

And changed the html for the raffle button to:

```
<button id="raffleBtn" type="submit" disabled>
     Raffle
</button>
```

And added the following JQuery code:

```
$('[name=attendance]').change(function() {
    if ($('[name=attendance]:checked').length >= 4
        && // CONDITION IF ENBANC CASE IS NOT ZERO
        && // CONDITION IF IT'S A VALID DAY) {
         $('#raffleBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
     } else {
         $('#raffleBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
});
```

My only problem is that I don't know how to get the value of `enBancCount` and `validDay` using JQuery.

Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
var enBancAccount = "${sessionScope.enBancCount}";
var validDay = "${sessionScope.validDay}";
```