# How do I access session attributes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

`${sessionScope.cart}`, how do I use this in a jQuery function where "cart" is a set of objects with price and quantity.

I need to show the total of price*quantity.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479866/get-servlet-session-attributes-using-jquery